# how to make Skype Profile Photo public?

Tags: macos, skype, ios

I use Skype on both my Mac desktop and my iPhone.

Unlike most introverts, I'd actually like to be more extroverted and I'd like to make my Skype profile photo truly public, but it looks like the 2020 version of Skype for all things Apple makes the profile photos hidden by default.  The [most recent Microsoft answer I see (from end of 2017)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/changing-profile-picture-privacy-settings/3acca924-8241-4ce2-bc23-d6be3ec6c06d) says:

> It looks like you're using the new Skype for Mac application. In this version, it is designed that people who are not yet part of your contacts list will only be seeing initials of your name but not your profile photo since you have not shared profile information yet with them. There is no option to make your profile picture appear on their end until you became contacts in Skype.

Is there a way to make profile photos public on any current Skype version on any (even non-Apple) devices?  Or are we stuck with only initials if we are not connected as contacts?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is **YES** there is an option for that

I use Skype a lot for work

the current version i use is 8.61.0.87 for Windows 10

and that option you are asking is as follow

1. Go to Settings
   [image]
2. then click on Profile and account
   [image]
3. and there should be a section named "Visibility", where you can check the public option so everyone on skype can see your profile picture

[image]

Edit: also to add to this answer
over on my mobile device i use an Android phone
Skype Version 8.61.0.96 on Android 9
it's pretty much the same path to that setting you are asking

Press your profile picture>scroll down to button Settings>press Profile and Account>Press Profile Picture and there should be the same Visibility option as PC version of Skype

Sorry for the spanish text.

Hope it helps!